# Como instanciar uma model e obter seus recursos pelo seu nome no Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvc, classes-abstratas, instanciar-objeto

Sendo que possuo a classe abstrata `User`, e suas sub-classes `Client Employee` e `Admin`, gostaria de renderizar telas de acordo com a subclasse escolhida.

Assim sendo:
    `users/_form.html.erb` : deve conter uma caixa de seleção com as subclasses de `Users`, e assim que selecionada uma subclasse eu possa instancia-la ou renderizar seu formulário.

> Exemplo: ao usuário selecionar `Colaborador` é renderizado
>   employees/_form.html.erb`.

```
  Se alguém puder também dar uma dica ou exemplo de como implementar.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas acredito que isto possa te dar um insight.

```
# app/controlles/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.is_a?(Employee)
      render 'employees/edit'
    end

    # Se preferir podes fazer algo dinâmico.
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Não existe classe abstrata em Ruby, e acredito que você não terá ganho em implementar isso.

O que eu te sugiro é implementar apenas um modelo caso ClientEmployee e Admin sejam parecidos, e diferenciar os dois através de um campo "tipo" no BD, por exemplo.

A outra sugestão, caso sejam bastante diferentes é criar um modelo User com o código e campos em comum e dois modelos ClientEmployee e Admin herdando dele. Assim você iria criar um controlador para cada um...

Answer (score 1):

Melhor solução na minha visão:  Crie um model User apenas e um atributo booleano admin. Desta forma você pode fazer ifs nas views:

```
<% if @user.admin? %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Não use um atributo chamado **type** para diferenciar os usuários normais de admins. Se for preciso use qualquer outro nome. O nome de atributo **type** é reservado no rails para fazer [Single-Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance), algo que é muito mais elaborado e complicado do que você precisa.